# Lubuntu 18.10 not recognizing touch pad

Tags: touchpad

I'm a newbie with Linux and installed Lubuntu 18.10 on an old VAIO.  It runs the programs I want but does not recognize the touchpad.  I can move the cursor alright but screen taps are not responded to.

I would appreciate any suggestions offered.